# Speech to Text on Android with custom unusual word matching

Tags: java, android, speech-to-text, soundex, metaphone

I would like to be able to use Android's Speech-To-Text engine to recognize a variety of unusual words in sentences.

To give an example, the word "electroencephalograph" comes out of STT as "electronics supply graph". When I use Soundex or Metaphone to compare what is spoken to a hard-coded value, the value seem to never match or randomly match. If I use a threshold (Math.abs(str1.compareTo(str2)) <= 1, for example), then the matching becomes very loose and almost anything will match.

In essence, what I would like to do is similar to looking up quotes from a quote-database by reciting the quote. The problem seems to be more in the limited wordset used by Google's Speech-To-Text engine.

Any ideas?

Comment: If Google engine is limited, you have always an option to use another engine, for example [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/)

Comment: I've seen CMUSphinx mentioned several places, but is it something that can be included in a normal Android app? It looks like you have to build it for your device, so is it feasible for an Android store app?

Comment: CMUSphinx can be used in Android store app just like any other software library

Answer (score 3):

You could try [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) with or without grammar-based speech recognition.

Look at the [Inimesed](https://github.com/Kaljurand/Inimesed) app. This is an open-source Android app which does JSGF-based speech recognition using CMUSphinx. In this case the grammar is compiled on the basis of the user's address book. You could simply throw out this part and have a fixed grammar that contains all your phrases.

If the problem is more that you have free-form sentences which contain occasional unusual words then grammar-based speech recognition might not work. In this case recognize with the n-gram language model but include all the unusual words in the dictionary.